do planes go into a circle pattern to avoid law enforcement?
do planes depart airport (A) circle a few times then land at the same airport (A) to indicate to another plane inflight it is safe to land at (A) that airport by eluding from any possible law enforcement?

Going around the pattern and landing again is extremely common for a flight student (often with several touch-and-gos where they land but don't stop and immediately take off again).  This sounds a lot like somebody looking at a flight tracker and making things up.

That sounds improbable. There are various explanations for a plane taking off & flying as described, but the one offered sounds more like something out of a badly written movie script than anything realistic.
Airplanes have radios; transmitting something innocuous ("test 1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1") on an arranged frequency at an arranged time would be far easier and would attract far less attention.
What's described sounds extremely far-fetched.
